# How to implement banners like FlipKart using google DFP

Tags: android, google-dfp

I have uploaded several ads related my products like food,travel,etc in google DFP server.

Now I want to implement banners view like in flipkart in my android app to show some recommendations based on user usage data by fetching from google DFP server.

[image]

In one way I can implement like

with single adUnitId for every banner I can pass some user data and fetch corresponding ad and display.

ex:

```
PublisherAdRequest adRequest = 
                         new PublisherAdRequest.Builder()
                        .addCustomTargeting("user_city","Bangalore")
                        .build();
     mPublisherAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Instead of fetching single ad for every banner in viewPager,
is there any better solution like I will pass user usage data to DFP server and in return it should give array of ads.

Comment: This is not generated by the google ads. The ads show here is custom ads which are just the cardview with viewpager they are loading simply images to this cardview. Flipkart tie up with so many brands and those brands are paying to Flipkart for main page advertisements so they are creating custom ads.

Comment: I have uploaded several ads related my products like food,travel,etc in google DFP server.
Now I want to show some recommendations based on user usage data by fetching from google DFP server.

Answer (score -1):

i did same like this without any api using recycler view.you can achieve this using horizontal recycler view with card view .

Comment: my question is related fetching ads from google DFP. Not related to recycler view!!